# Apache rewrite redirects exceeded

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my `apache.conf`code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # if request is not for a file/directory 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    # then skip from rewrites
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # add www to hostname
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # forward all the requests to `/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, this results in a `500 error`, that states:

`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: Specifically what input URL causes a redirect loop? Have you found a URL that does not loop?  Looking at this, I would place the rewrite related to https://www. _before_ the block which ignores rewrites for real files and directories.  More commonly, those would be grouped with the `index.php` rewrite you have at the end.

Comment: Also, it's more common to use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}`  than SCRIPT_FILENAME.  I would probably start by moving that block down below the https part and just above the index.php part.